# How to control an m4a file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am playing m4a files that require that I use a NetStream object and want to control the audio with a SoundChannel object (because that is the only way I know to sync an HSlider control with an audio file). My problem is that I cannot connect the Sound Channel with the audio source. The event handler button1_clickHandler does not even regognize the existance of the SoundChannel object. Is there a way to control this type of audio file with a SoundChannel? If not, how can I set the position of the HSlider-- I've tried using HSlider.value, but that somehow gets overridden.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="init()">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private var audioExample:AudioExample_M4A;
            public function init():void{
                audioExample = new AudioExample_M4A();
            }
            private function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void{
                if(audioExample.soundChannel){
                    audioExample.soundChannel.stop()
                    trace("Yes")
                }else{
                    trace("No")
                }

            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:Button label="Play / Pause"  click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</mx:Application>
```

Here is the class file AudioExample_M4A.as:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.media.SoundChannel;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;

    public class AudioExample_M4A extends Sprite {
        public var soundChannel:SoundChannel= new SoundChannel();;
        public var temp:String = new String()

        public var audioURL:String = "badge.m4a";
        private var connection:NetConnection;
        public var stream:NetStream;

        public function AudioExample_M4A() {
            connection = new NetConnection();
            connection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
            connection.connect(null);
        }


        private function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {
            switch (event.info.code) {
                case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                    connectStream();
                    break;
                case "NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound":
                    break;
            }
        }

        private function connectStream():void {
            stream = new NetStream(connection);
            stream.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
            stream.client={onMetaData:function(obj:Object):void{
                trace("metadata: duration=" + obj.duration);
                }
            }
            soundChannel = stream.play(audioURL) as SoundChannel;
        }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** control a `NetStream` object with a `SoundChannel` object. These are two *completely* different methods to playing media and, as far as I know, do not share a common base.

To allow for a slider to control the pointer position, you need to do the following:

- Get the slider position as a percentage (`slider.position * slider.minimum/slider.maximum` in Spark, not sure about in MX)
- Get the duration of the song. This is retrieved via `NetStream.onMetaData`
- Call `NetStream.seek()` with an argument of slider percentage multiplied by duration (`seek()` expects the value in seconds). So `NetStream.seek( duration * positionPercentage )`